# How anonymous is a stack exchange account?

Tags: anonymity

Sorry I have to be a bit vague here.  Suppose I need to know how to do something completely legal and ethical but have reason to avoid having the question connected to me to the knowledge of persons who may be looking for such questions.  These people do NOT have NSA resources, but they are a lot more capable than a mere Google search.  If I use Tor to create a new SE account with a throwaway address, do I need to NOT have the address on a domain that I own?

Comment: I realize criminals would probably claim to be legal.  Oh, well.

Comment: Is there a possibility that those people have read this post, and could therefore correlate your future anonymous questions to your current (un-anonymous) account? ;-) This might be of use: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously. Note that you don't have to confirm your email address to be able to post from a temporary, cookie-based account.

Comment: It's possible that they read this post, but unlikely.  It's not me they're hunting for, it's the topic of my anonymous question.  Obviously if I hint at what it is here, I'll have ruined it.  :-)  But thanks for the reminder about not logging in.  I forgot that questions were allowed that way.

Answer (score 1):

> .. avoid having the question connected to me ..
>   .. do I need to NOT have the address on a domain that I own?

If you can avoid it, then by all means avoid it.

Whether you **need** to, depends on the capabilities of your adversary, but using the same domain that millions of others use makes you disappear much better than one that only you use *and own*.
(Unless you own yahoo of course :)